# Math issue: place circles around the clock

Tags: java, math, draw, geometry

Look at the gray circles along the lines, they need to be placed equally to represent the hours, here is my code for that, where did I go wrong?

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        c.drawCircle(140*(float)Math.cos((double) (i*30))+ width/2,
                     140*(float) Math.sin((double) (i*30)) + height/2,  1,  p);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @Dabiel Mendel: If one of the answers below was useful, you should accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The angle must be provided to [Math.cos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29) in radians (between `0` and `2*Math.PI`).

So, instead of

```
Math.cos((double) (i*30))
```

Use

```
Math.cos(i*Math.PI/6.0)
```

Note that I also removed the useless cast to double : multiplying an int and a double already produces a double.

Comment: ahh thank you, it's been long since i last used sin and cos, hehe, such a dumb question :)

Comment: You should use [java.lang.Math.toRadians()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians%28double%29).

Answer (score 4):

`Math.sin` and `Math.cos` operate on angles in radians and not degrees. To correct, multiply by pi and divide by 180.

Comment: ahh thank you, it's been long since i last used sin and cos, hehe, such a dumb question :)